# Is it good practice to include <c:out> in external javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jsp

We do a lot of JSP with jQuery/javascript, to make the code more reusable, most of the javascript are thrown to an external library and then import to the jsp file. However, unavoidably some of the values to be used in javascript has to be predefined by java/jsp, that means there is going to have some cases like this

```
alert('<c:out value="${i18n_alert_msg}"');
```

I know we can always put such thing as parameters of the function, but it could be very nasty when there is a lot of places like this, make parameter list long and redundant.

So just wondering if it is a good practice just leave the `<c:out/>` in the javascript file

Comment: No, it's not good, because you'd have to configure your server to process your JavaScript files as JSP. That'd mean clients could not cache the files, which is (generally considered) bad. In a typically-configured J2EE application, it won't work.

Comment: @Pointy thanks, then what is a better solution to achieve js code reusable? Rather than put 10 parameters or one array with 20 elements as parameter?

Comment: You can put dynamic content into your main pages and have the JavaScript find that via DOM APIs. That way your JavaScript can be cached, and yet it still has access to the per-page information.

Comment: Create a common/utility (REST/vanilla AJAX) service which would send the messages to client side whatever/whenever needed and call the service from client as per need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your front end code should be dynamic not the code file itself, which would cause performance issue.

Create a common/utility (REST/vanilla AJAX) service which would send the messages to client side whatever/whenever needed and call the service from client as per need.

Comment: example depends upon your requirement, can you provide some code/message that you need to send to client and your (business) logic behind it, just to understand if that can be stored in web storage/cookies.

Comment: just like above example, a dynamic alert message, or max amount requirement which set by java, or a given locale defined by java, all above three cases are something predefined by java and can be used by javascript.

Comment: service call is not required not for each value, have the call for bunch of messages as per need, no need for separate call for each value

Comment: Create a JSON for => dynamic alert messages, or max amount requirement which set by java, or a given locale in servlet response, and have this asked from client when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

no value 'has to be predefined'. your js code can take data from request, cookies or, the most flexible and powerful way, simply fetch them from server.

you can build fully dynamic one-page-application using only static resources so for sure you don't need this feature. don't make js nor css files dynamic - let clients cache them

Comment: Thanks,  "the most flexible and powerful way, simply fetch them from server." -- do you mean sever session or could you please give an example or url of the example?

Comment: just make an ajax request from your js

Comment: I see, so it is like an ajax request to the servlet code to retrieve the value - that still sounds like an overkill: each value requires an additional ajax/json call..

Comment: nope, it's the most common practice. you don't need 1 call per value. you can do 1 call for all necessary values

Comment: that require a logic in the server side to put all these values into a Map, I assume, Then in the js side there is global map to hold the value then it can be visible everywhere. Is that right?